Groß-/Kleinschreibung bei Überschriften, die mit "/" getrennt sind
Wenn ich bei einer Überschrift die ersten beiden Wörter mit einem Schrägstrich trenne, werden dann beide Wörter groß geschrieben, auch wenn diese normalerweise klein geschrieben werden?
Zum Beispiel:

Soziale/Emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten

oder

Soziale/emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten


Diese Varianten sind richtig:

Soziale/emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten
Soziale / emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten
Soziale und emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten

Auch denkbar:

Emotionale soziale Bedürfnisse der Klienten
Sozialemotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten
Sozioemotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten

Das ist falsch. (Die Begründung folgt weiter unten):

Soziale/Emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten

Mein persönlicher Rat lautet, auf den Schrägstrich zu verzichten und stattdessen eine dieser beiden Variante zu verwenden:


Soziale und emotionale Bedürfnisse der Klienten
Emotionale soziale Bedürfnisse der Klienten


Variante 1 umfasst alle sozialen Bedürfnisse, egal, ob sie mit Emotionen verbunden sind oder nicht, und zusätzlich auch alle emotionalen Bedürfnisse, egal ob sie mit der sozialen Situation der Klienten zu tun haben oder nicht.
Variante 2 greift aus den sozialen Bedürfnissen nur jene Bedürfnisse heraus, die auch emotional sind.

Warum ist »Soziale/Emotionale« falsch?
Das amtliche Regelwerk des Rates für deutsche Rechtschreibung 2024 wurde auf der Grundlage des Beschlusses des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung vom 15.12.2023 im Jahr 2024 übereinstimmend beschlossen. Die folgenden Zitate stammen aus diesem Dokument.

E Zeichensetzung
Vorbemerkungen
...
Für Verkürzungen und Zusammenziehungen steht der Schrägstrich zur Verfügung (Abschn. 12, § 83).
...


12 Schrägstrich
Der Schrägstrich zeigt an, dass Wortgruppen, Wörter, Wortteile, Zahlen
oder andere Ausdrücke zusammengehören. Zusammengehörig sind die mit
dem Schrägstrich gekennzeichneten Ausdrücke entweder im Sinne von und,
oder, bzw., bis (1) oder im Sinne von pro, je (2).
§ 83 Der Schrägstrich zeigt die Zusammengehörigkeit sprachlicher Ausdrücke an.

Es folgen Beispiele zu (1 und, oder, bzw.) für Wortgruppen (die Schneeglöckchen / die Krokusse als Frühblüher), Wörter (Abfahrt vom Dienstort/Wohnort), Wortteile (die Schüler/-innen der Realschule), Zahlen (am 1./2. März) und andere Ausdrücke (die SPÖ/ÖVP-Koalition), dann Beispiele zu (2 pro, je) (1000 Einwohner/km2)
Dann folgen Hinweise, unter anderem über die Verwendung von Leerzeichen vor und nach dem Schrägstrich. (Die Verwendung von keinem Leerzeichen ist immer erlaubt, nur ein Leerzeichen zu verwenden ist nie erlaubt, beide Leerzeichen dürfen nur bei Wörtern und Wortgruppen verwendet werden.)
Über Schrägstriche steht sonst nicht mehr in diesem Dokument. Insbesondere werden Schrägstriche nicht als Zeichen beschrieben, nach denen groß weiter zu schreiben ist, und ein Beispiel demonstriert das sogar:

Kaffee mit/ohne Schlagobers

In dem Abschnitt über den Schrägstrich wird auch sonst nicht angeführt, dass er irgendwie die Groß-/Kleinschreibung beeinflusst. Daher gelten alle Regeln zur Großschreibung unverändert.
(Der Schrägstrich spielt auch bei der Gliederung des Dokuments eine Rolle, das wird in dem Dokument erklärt, das ist aber keine Rechtschreibregel und außerhalb des Dokuments irrelevant.)

Sehen wir uns also an, was das amtliche Regelwerk über Groß- und Kleinschreibung zu sagen hat:

D Groß- und Kleinschreibung
Vorbemerkungen
(1) Die Großschreibung, das heißt die Schreibung mit einem großen Anfangsbuchstaben, dient den Schreibenden dazu, den Anfang bestimmter Texteinheiten sowie Wörter bestimmter Gruppen zu kennzeichnen und sie dadurch für die Lesenden hervorzuheben.
(2) Die Großschreibung wird im Deutschen verwendet zur Kennzeichnung von

Überschriften, Werktiteln und dergleichen
Satzanfängen
Substantiven und Substantivierungen
Eigennamen mit ihren nichtsubstantivischen Bestandteilen
bestimmten festen nominalen Wortgruppen mit nichtsubstantivischen Bestandteilen
Anredepronomen und Anreden


In Ziffer (3) steht, dass neben Regeln für Großschreibung auch Regeln für Kleinschreibung notwendig sind und Ziffer (4) enthält im Wesentlichen ein Inhaltsverzeichnis des Abschnitts D. Danach folgt:

1 Kennzeichnung des Anfangs bestimmter Texteinheiten
durch Großschreibung
§ 53 Das erste Wort einer Überschrift, eines Werktitels, einer Anschrift und dergleichen wird großgeschrieben.

Dieser Paragraph bezieht sich ausdrücklich nur auf das erste Wort. Es ist also immer nur ein einziges Wort am Anfang einer Überschrift großzuschreiben. Alle anderen Wörter in einer Überschrift sind so zu schreiben, wie sonst auch immer, also so, als stünden sie mitten in einem längeren Satz.
Es folgen sehr viele Regeln über Großschreibung in diesem Dokument, aber keine einzige dieser Regeln verlangt, dass das Adjektiv »emotionale«, das als gewöhnliches Attribut in einer Nominalphrase verwendet wird, groß zu schreiben wäre. Daher ist es klein zu schreiben.

Im Duden habe ich folgenden Ausschnitt gefunden: "Weiterhin kann man ihn [den Schrägstrich; Anm.] verwenden, um mehrere gleichberechtigte Möglichkeiten platzsparend zusammenzufassen: Schüler/-innen, und/oder. Wenn diese Alternation am Anfang eines Satzes steht, müssen Sie darauf achten, dass alle entsprechenden Wörter großgeschrieben werden – denn theoretisch könnte der Satz mit jedem dieser Wörter beginnen: Ich/Wir bestätige(n) hiermit, dass …".
Da alle der mit "/" getrennten Wörter am Anfang der Überschrift stehen könnten, frage ich mich, ob hier diese Regel auch zutrifft?

@Chrisi: Der Duden ist nicht mehr das, was er mal war. Das, was in dem von dir zitierten Artikel steht, ist die Privatmeinung der Duden-Redaktion. Die Meinung dieser Redaktion zählt seit 1996 aber nicht mehr als die Meinung jeder anderen nicht-amtlichen Quelle. Insbesondere widerspricht dieser Artikel weiter unten sogar explizit den amtlichen Regeln, denn weiter unten heißt es über das Setzen von Leerzeichen vor und ...

... nach einem Schrägstrich: »Leider gibt es dafür in den amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln keine eindeutige Festlegung.« Das ist glatt gelogen! Diese angeblich nichtexistente Regelung steht im amtlichen Regelwerk in den Hinweisen zu § 83. Sie nehmen in diesem Dokument die obere Hälfte der Seite 153 ein. Ich habe das, was dort laut Duden nicht steht, in meiner Antwort bereits sinngemäß zitiert. In Bezug auf die konkrete Fragestellung möchte ich meine Empfehlung wiederholen, eine Formulierung ohne Schrägstrich zu verwenden.

Richtiggehende Regel gibt es für einen solchen Fall keine, weil Trennungen mit einem Schrägstrich nicht unter die "reguläre" Interpunktion fallen.
Tatsächlich lautet mein Rat, solche Konstruktionen - insbesondere in Überschriften - zu vermeiden und durch Formulierungen wie

Soziale und emotionale Bedürfnisse [...]
Soziale oder emotionale Bedürfnisse [...]
Sozial-emotionale Bedürfnisse [...]
Soziale im Gegensatz zu emotionalen Bedürfnissen [...]

zu ersetzen. Erstens ist nämlich nicht klar, wofür der Schrägstrich steht: "und"? "oder"? etwas anderes? Zweitens sollte man Überschriften auch zitieren können. Das geht bei einem herkömmlich formulierten Titel gut, aber stellen wir uns jemanden vor, der seinem Kollegen sagt:

Stell' dir vor, da habe ich grade ein tolles Paper gelesen, das hatte den Titel Soziale Schrägstrich emotionale Bedürfnisse ...

Die zu erwartende Antwort darauf lautet dann vermutlich "Hochkomma, Backslash, Fragezeichen, verwirrter Smilie"!
Zwinkersmilie!

Beim Bindestrich wäre ich vorsichtig. Der trägt eher nicht die Bedeutung des Schrägstrichs.

@tofro: der Schrägstrich trägt überhaupt keine Bedeutung - wengstens keine, die festgelegt wäre. Ich habe deshalb einfach eine (sicher unvollständige) Liste von möglichen infrage kommenden Bedeutungen aufgeführt. Gut möglich, daß "sozial-emotionale" der beabsichtigten Bedeutung nicht entspricht, aber: was weiß ich?

RdRSR, Kap.12: Der Schrägstrich zeigt an, dass Wortgruppen, Wörter, Wortteile, Zahlen oder andere Ausdrücke zusammengehören. Zusammengehörig sind die mit dem Schrägstrich gekennzeichneten Ausdrücke entweder im Sinne von und, oder, bzw., bis oder im Sinne von pro, je.

Zitat: »Richtiggehende Regel gibt es für einen solchen Fall keine« Doch, doch! Richtiggehenden Regeln für einen solchen Fall gibt es. Sie stehen im amtliche Regelwerk des Rates für deutsche Rechtschreibung und ich habe sie in meiner Antwort zitiert.

Substantive, Eigennamen und Wörter am Satzanfang werden großgeschrieben - keines der Kriterien trifft zu.
Also schreibt man es klein.

Es gibt noch ein paar Sachen mehr, die aber auch alle nicht zutreffen.

Eine Überschrift (und um die geht's ja) ist i.A. ja auch kein Satz

@tofro: Wenn Du in der Überschrift durchgängig Großschreibung nutzt, dann nutzt Du durchgängig Großschreibung und fragst nicht. In allen anderen Fällen schreibst Du's richtig.

Eine Regel dafür kenne ich nicht.
Pragmatisch betrachtet: Da ein Schrägstrich i.A. im weitesten Sinne "und" bzw. "oder" bedeutet, würde ich so weiterschreiben, wie das nach "und" oder "oder" richtig wäre (in deinem Beispiel also klein).
